# Is there a way to generate a vega(-lite) graph from java (other than programming one, from scratch)?

Tags: java, visualization, vega-lite, vega, language-binding

I have recently evaluated freely available software-packages / frameworks for producing complex, flexible and high quality graphics of statistical data for displaying such data in a machine-learning - environment, which I am currently developing in java.

The most promising framework for my use-case seems to be the **vega(-lite)** one. However, I was stunned, when I couldn't find any **binding** to the **java** programming-language, as it seems to be widely used with existing bindings to python, R, julia and many other languages...

...did I miss something?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can't you just generate the JSON?

Comment: @user2373145: Thx for your return-question. Yes, I can create json from java, that wouldn't be a problem. But I'd much prefer a more coupled *binding* to d3/vega, as I want to display dynamic data whilst being generated (adding and subtracting json-nodes). Also, I'm expecting large amounts of data, in bursts (some idle time, then some burst, etc.). So accessing the json-structure for modification is really the only option, hence my question. I can create mostly anything on the java-side of things, but I'm rather new to d3/vega, so I'm not sure, how to connect the 2 to a common data-structure.

Comment: I don't know whether a binding between the Vega Javascript APIs and Java exists.

Comment: Actually, there's a list of language bindings here, and Java isn't on the list: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/ecosystem.html#bindings-for-programming-languages